# Unknown Issue running swift iOS app after connecting to database

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

This is the first time I've connected an iOS app to a database so it is all pretty new to me.

All of the code is finally working and there aren't any errors. But when I run the app then try to open the VC with the tableview that is reading the information, it freezes and I get this:

```
    0x100030610 <+0>:  sub    sp, sp, #0x20             ; =0x20 
    0x100030614 <+4>:  stp    x29, x30, [sp, #0x10]
    0x100030618 <+8>:  add    x29, sp, #0x10            ; =0x10 
    0x10003061c <+12>: str    x0, [sp, #0x8]
    0x100030620 <+16>: mov    x0, x1
    0x100030624 <+20>: mov    x1, x2
    0x100030628 <+24>: bl     0x100041688               ; symbol stub for: swift_conformsToProtocol
    0x10003062c <+28>: str    x0, [sp]
    0x100030630 <+32>: cbz    x0, 0x100030648           ; <+56>
    0x100030634 <+36>: ldr    x0, [sp, #0x8]
    0x100030638 <+40>: ldr    x1, [sp]
    0x10003063c <+44>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp, #0x10]
    0x100030640 <+48>: add    sp, sp, #0x20             ; =0x20 
    0x100030644 <+52>: ret    
->  0x100030648 <+56>: brk    #0x1
```

What does it mean?

Why is it stopping me from loading the tableview?

This is the VC I want to load:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()






    self.parksTable.delegate = self
    self.parksTable.dataSource = self



    // For Data
    let homeModel = HomeModel()
    homeModel.delegate = self as! HomeModelProtocol
    homeModel.downloadItems()

}


// For Data
func itemsDownloaded(items: NSArray) {

    feedItems = items
    self.parksTable.reloadData()
}



     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return feedItems.count
    }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cellIdentifier: String = "parkCell"
        let myCell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier)!
        // Get the location to be shown
        let item: LocationModel = feedItems[indexPath.row] as! LocationModel
        // Get references to labels of cell
        myCell.textLabel!.text = item.parkName

        return myCell
}
```

This is for the data:

```
lass LocationModel: NSObject {



//properties

var parkID: Int?
var parkName: String?
var parkLatitude: String?
var parkLongitude: String?
var parkDescription: String?


//empty constructor

override init()
{

}

//construct with @name, @address, @latitude, and @longitude parameters

init(parkID: Int, parkName: String, parkLatitude: String, parkLongitude: String, parkDescription: String) {

    self.parkID = parkID
    self.parkName = parkName
    self.parkLatitude = parkLatitude
    self.parkLongitude = parkLongitude
    self.parkDescription = parkDescription
}


//prints object's current state

override var description: String {
    return "Park Name: \(parkName), Latitude: \(parkLatitude), Longitude: \(parkLongitude), Park Description: \(parkDescription)"

}
```

}

This is also for the data:

```
class HomeModel: NSObject, URLSessionDataDelegate{





    weak var delegate: HomeModelProtocol!

    var data = Data()

    let urlPath: String = "http://gamingkc.com/service.php"

func downloadItems() {

    let url: URL = URL(string: urlPath)!
    let defaultSession = Foundation.URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)

    let task = defaultSession.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print("Failed to download data")
        }else {
            print("Data downloaded")
            self.parseJSON(data!)
        }

    }

    task.resume()
}


func parseJSON(_ data:Data) {

    var jsonResult = NSArray()

    do{
        jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSArray

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)

    }

    var jsonElement = NSDictionary()
    let parks = NSMutableArray()

    for i in 0 ..< jsonResult.count
    {

        jsonElement = jsonResult[i] as! NSDictionary

        let park = LocationModel()

        //the following insures none of the JsonElement values are nil through optional binding
        if let parkName = jsonElement["Park Name"] as? String,
            let parkLatitude = jsonElement["Latitude"] as? String,
            let parkLongitude = jsonElement["Longitude"] as? String,
            let parkDescription = jsonElement["Park Description"] as? String

        {

            park.parkName = parkName
            park.parkLatitude = parkLatitude
            park.parkLongitude = parkLongitude
            park.parkDescription = parkDescription

        }

        parks.add(park)

    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in

        self.delegate.itemsDownloaded(items: parks)

    })
```

}

Comment: please show some code

Comment: While I put together some code for you to look at can you elaborate any on what that is that pops up on Xcode when I try to go to that VC? The bottom line is highlighted in green.

Comment: Please replace `let myCell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier)!` with `let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath)` and then try running the code

Comment: My issue is not solved by that change.

Comment: Ok please add `print(feedItems)` inside `cellForRowAt` method and see what it prints?

Comment: 2017-09-17 00:38:29.471155-0500 Metropolitan League 1.5.1[2204:596471] Unknown class _TtC25Metropolitan_League_1_5_110parksTable in Interface Builder file.              Is the console output I get.

Comment: What is the name of your TableViewController class?

Comment: The View Controller containing a TableView with the class of parksTable is called ParkTableViewController.

Comment: Have you set this class in storyboard?

Comment: Yes - of course

Comment: Have you used `parksTable` in your storyboard anywhere?

Comment: for the UITableView I have in the ParksTableViewController - yes.

Comment: please show the complete code for your tableViewController class, if you can please attach the screenshot of storyboard where you are using `parksTable` class

Comment: Can you tell me what you're looking for?

Comment: The error you told me before ` Unknown class _TtC25Metropolitan_League_1_5_110parksTable in Interface Builder file.` tells me that something is wrong with storyboard setting thats why I am saying that please show the code and screenshot

Comment: You still haven't answered my original question. Which is way more important to me than you looking at my storyboard settings.

Comment: You won't get help if you don't provide the info you were asked for..

Comment: I won't get help if the questions I ask are ignored.. I don't need to provide screenshots of storyboard settings in order for someone to help me better understand what is showing up. I answered his questions and then some - it's time he answer the very first question I asked him.

Comment: If you will comment this line: homeModel.delegate = self as! HomeModelProtocol, will the table view continue loading? It won't get any data, just need to be sure that it will finish loading

Comment: 2017-09-17 13:59:27.277280-0500 Metropolitan League 1.5.2[2424:687499] fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Will someone answer my question?